# Axios FormData is sending null values to backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, mern

I am building a MERN Application in which I am sending user name and email from react to Node.js
The formData is printing correctly but when I use axios to send the data to backend(localhost:5000/register) is is giving me an null values(req.body = undefined). Please help me solve this.

server.js

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

router.get('/home',(req,res)=>{
  res.send('This is home page 1');
});

router.post('/register',async(req, res) => {
  console.log('reached Backend');
  const name = req.body.name;
  const email = req.body.email;
  console.log(req.body);
  // try{
  //     const user = new collection1({name,email});
  //     await user.save();
  //     res.status(201).json({message: "registered succussfully"});
  //   }
  //   catch(err) {
  //     console.log(err);
  //   }
  });

  app.use("/",router);
async function initServer(){
  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
  app.listen(PORT,()=>
  console.log(`express server is running on the  port ${PORT}`))
}


initServer();
```

Front-end App.js

```
const App= () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    name:"",
    email:"",
  });
  let name, value;
  const handleInput = (e) => {
    name = e.target.name;
    value = e.target.value;

    setUser({...user,[name]:value});
}
const handleSubmit=async(e) =>{
  e.preventDefault()
  const formData = new FormData();
  console.log("username",user.name);
  formData.append('name', user.name)
  formData.append('email', user.email)
  for (var key of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(key[0] + ', ' + key[1]);
}

  console.log("trying th reach backend");
  await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/register", formData,{
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
  }).then(res => {
      console.log('res:',res);
      window.alert("Registration  Successful");
  }).catch((err)=>{
      console.log("Failed to reach bachend")
       console.error(err.response.data);
  })
}

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form method = "POST" encType="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="name" value={user.name} id="name" onChange={handleInput}></input>
        <input type="email" name="email" value={user.email} id="email" onChange={handleInput}></input>
        <input type="submit" name="App" id="App" value="App" onClick={handleSubmit} ></input>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

> ```
> headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
> ```

You are missing the mandatory boundary parameter. You also have no way of knowing what it needs to be. **Omit** that and let the browser infer the correct content-type from the FormData object.

> ```
> app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
> app.use(bodyParser.json());
> ```

You don't have a middware capable of parsing multipart form data.

Add one.

---

Alternatively, since you aren't dealing with files, stop trying to use multipart form data.

Replace `FormData` with [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) and post URL encoded form data which `bodyParser.urlencoded` can handle.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving JSON in the backend why do you send FormData?
You can try using `express-formidable` or `express-form-data`

I'm not 100% sure about this 'cause I usually send the data through JSON.

BTW: Body parser is deprecated. Try using `express.json()`.